# How can I find the row error for a table without an auto-increment?

Tags: mysql, indexing, collation, alter-table

I'm trying to convert an indexed column (not unique) varchar(255) to use utf8mb4_general_ci collation.  But I keep running into max key errors.

So I tried limited my varchar length to lower numbers and receive this error:

```
Data too long for column at 'table_name' at row 122
```

But my table does not have auto-increment ids, so I'm stuck at figuring out where row 122 is.

My hunch is that there's just a few long records that I might be able to truncate to fit the 767 key length for utf8mb4.  But I need to find the long strings first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the longest strings ('foo' being your column name that is too long):

```
SELECT *, char_length(foo)
FROM table_name
ORDER BY char_length(foo) DESC
LIMIT 25
```